# Data Consistency Across Microservices

Tags: design-patterns, akka, microservices, data-consistency

While each microservice generally will have its own data - certain entities are required to be consistent across multiple services.

For such data consistency requirement in a highly distributed landscape such as microservices architecture, what are the choices for design? Of course, I do not want shared database architecture, where a single DB manages the state across all the services. That violates isolation and shared-nothing principles.

I do understand that, a microservice can publish an event when an entity is created, updated or deleted. All other microservices which are interested in this event can accordingly update the linked entities in their respective databases.

This is workable, however it leads to a lot of careful and coordinated programming effort across the services.

Can Akka or any other framework solve this use case? How?

**EDIT1:**
Adding the below diagram for clarity. 

Basically, I am trying to understand, if there are available frameworks today that can solve this data consistency problem.

For the queue I can use any AMQP software such as RabbitMQ or Qpid etc. 
For the data consistency framework, I am not sure if presently Akka or any other software can help. Or is this scenario so uncommon, and such an anti-pattern that no framework should be ever needed?
[image]

Answer (score 13):

The Microservices architectural style tries to allow organizations to have small teams own services independent in development and at runtime. See this [read](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html). And the hardest part is to define the service boundaries in a useful way. When you discover that the way you split up your application results in requirements impacting multiple services frequently that would tell you to rethink the service boundaries. The same is true for when you feel a strong need to share entities between the services.

So the general advice would be to try very hard to avoid such scenarios. However there may be cases where you cannot avoid this. Since a good architecture is often about making the right trade-offs, here some ideas.

1. Consider expressing the dependency using service interfaces (API) instead of a direct DB dependency. That would allow each service team to change their internal data schema as much as required and only worry about the interface design when it comes to dependencies. This is helpful because it is easier to add additional APIs and slowly deprecate older APIs instead of changing a DB design along with all dependent Microservices (potentially at the same time). In other words you are still able to deploy new Microservice versions independently, as long as the old APIs are still supported. This is the approach recommended by the Amazon CTO, who was pioneering a lot of the Microservices approach. Here is a recommended read of an [interview in 2006](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1142065) with him.
2. Whenever you really really cannot avoid using the same DBs and you are splitting your service boundaries in a way that multiple teams/services require the same entities, you introduce two dependencies between the Microservice team and the team that is responsible for the data scheme: a) Data Format, b) Actual Data. This is not impossible to solve, but only with some overhead in organization. And if you introduce too many of such dependencies your organization will likely be crippled and slowed down in development.

**a) Dependency on the data scheme**. The entities data format cannot be modified without requiring changes in the Microservices. To decouple this you will have to version the entities data scheme *strictly* and in the database support all versions of the data that the Microservices are currently using. This would allow the Microservices teams to decide for themselves when to update their service to support the new version of the data scheme. This is not feasible with all use cases, but it works with many.

**b) Dependency on the actual collected data.** The data that has been collected and is of a known version for a Microservice is OK to use, but the issue occurs when you have some services producing a newer version of the data and another service depends on it - But was not yet upgraded to being able to read the latest version. This problem is hard to solve and in many cases suggests you did not chose the service boundaries correctly. Typically you have no choice but to roll out all services that depend on the data at the same time as upgrading the data in the database. A more wacky approach is to write different versions of the data concurrently (which works mostly when the data is not mutable).

To solve both a) and b) in some other cases the dependency can be reduced by hidden data duplication and eventual consistency. Meaning each service stores its own version of the data and only modifies it whenever the requirements for that service change. The services can do so by listening to a public data flow. In such scenarios you would be using an event based architecture where you define a set of public events that can be queued up and consumed by listeners from the different services that will process the event and store whatever data out of it that is relevant for it (potentially creating data duplication). Now some other events may indicate that internally stored data has to be updated and it is each services responsibility to do so with its own copy of the data. A technology to maintain such a public event queue is [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/).

Comment: Diagram looks good, just make clear there is typically a `pull` from the Services to the queue and not a `push`. Akka will help with some other issues, like building a somewhat resilient messaging system and simplify deploying distributed services (only JVM based), but it will not help with the underlying problem of your application architecture design, like deciding where to draw service boundaries. That can only be answered by looking into your domain and application requirements. I'd recommend to also try learn more about what some large companies did in their architecture.

Answer (score 8):

**Theoretical Limitations**

One important caveat to remember is the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem):

> In the presence of a partition, one is then left with two options:
>   consistency or availability. When choosing consistency over
>   availability, the system will return an error or a time-out if
>   particular information cannot be guaranteed to be up to date due to
>   network partitioning.

So by "requiring" that certain entities are consistent across multiple services you increase the probability that you will have to deal with timeout issues.

**Akka Distributed Data**

Akka has a [distributed data module](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-data.html) to share information within a cluster:

> All data entries are spread to all nodes, or nodes with a certain
>   role, in the cluster via direct replication and gossip based
>   dissemination. You have fine grained control of the consistency level
>   for reads and writes.

Comment: thanks for the mention of Akka Distributed data. Does it work in the fashion I have shown in the diagram above? Can you please point me to such? 
Or if you know other frameworks that do, please post.

Comment: It's worth noting that akka clustering is really best for single, not multiple services. Trying to run multiple services in one akka cluster is more of a distributed monolith (aka the worst of both worlds).

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here. We have data in different microservices and there are cases where one service needs to know if there is a specific entity in another microservice. We do not want the services to call each others to complete a request because this adds response time and multipies downtimes. Also it adds a nightmare of coupling depth. The client should not decide about business logic and data validation/consistency either. We also do not want central services like "Saga Controllers" to provide for consistency between services.

So we use a Kafka message bus to inform observing services of state changes in "upstream" services. We try very hard not to miss or ignore any messages even in error conditions and we use Martin Fowler's "tolerant reader" pattern to couple as loosely as possible. Still sometimes services are changed and after the change they might need information from other services that they might have emitted on the bus before but they are now gone (even Kafka cannot store forever).

We decided for now that each Service be split in a pure and decoupled web service (RESTful) that does the actual work and a separate Connector-Service which listens to the Bus and may also call other services. This Connector runs in the background. It is only triggered by bus messages. It then will try to add data to the main service via REST calls. If the service responds with a consistency error, the connector will try to repair this by fetching the needed data from the upstream service and inject it as needed. (We cannot afford batch-jobs to "synchronize" data en block, so we just fetch what we need). If there are better ideas, we are always open, but "pull" or "just change data model" is not what we consider feasible...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can approach this issue from 2 angles, service collaboration and data modelling:

Service collaboration

Here you can choose between service orchestration and service choreography. You already mentioned the exchange of messages or events between services. This would be the choreography approach which as you said might work but involves writing code in each service that deals with the messaging part. I'm sure there are libraries for that though. Or you can choose service orchestration where you introduce a new composite service - the orchestrator, which can be responsible for managing the data updates between the services. Because the data consistency management is now extracted into a separate component, this would allow you to switch between eventual consistency and strong consistency without touching the downstream services.

Data modelling

You can also choose to redesign the data models behind the participating microservices and to extract the entities that are required to be consistent across multiple services into relationships managed by a dedicated relationship microservice. Such a microservice would be somewhat similar to the orchestrator but the coupling would be reduced because the relationships can be modelled in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 main forces at play here:

- decoupling - that's why you have microservices in the first place and want a shared-nothing approach to data persistence
- consistency requirement - if I understood correctly you're already fine with eventual consistency

The diagram makes perfect sense to me, but I don't know of any framework to do it out of the box, probably due to the many use-case specific trade-offs involved. I'd approach the problem as follows:

The upstream service emits events on to the message bus, as you've shown. For the purpose of serialisation I'd carefully choose the wire format that doesn't couple the producer and consumer too much. The ones I know of are protobuf and avro. You can evolve your event model upstream without having to change the downstream if it doesn't care about the newly added fields and can do a rolling upgrade if it does.

The downstream services subscribe to the events - the message bus must provide fault-tolerance. We're using kafka for this but since you chose AMQP I'm assuming it gives you what you need.

In case of network failures (e.g. the downstream consumer cannot connect to the broker) if you favour (eventual) consistency over availability you may choose to refuse to serve requests that rely on data that you know can be more stale than some preconfigured threshold.

Answer (score 0):

"accordingly update the linked entities in their respective databases" -> data duplication -> FAIL.

Using events to update other databases is identical to caching which brings cache consistency problem which is the problem you arise in your question.

Keep your local databases as separated as possible and use pull semantics instead of push, i.e. make RPC calls when you need some data and be prepared to gracefully handle possible errors like timeouts, missing data or service unavailability. Akka or Finagle gives enough tools to do that right.

This approach *might* hurt performance but at least you can choose what to trade and where. Possible ways to decrease latency and increase throughput are:

- scale data provider services so they can handle more req/sec with lower latency
- use local caches with short expiration time. That will introduce eventual consistency but really helps with performance.
- use distributed cache and face cache consistency problem directly

Comment: Based on what I see in the microservices world, can not agree with your remark that "data duplication -> FAIL." 
Usually you would go a long way to avoid duplication - however, I would not call it a fail.

Comment: I have added a diagram for clarity. Do you know if Akka or any other framework would help in this use case? Appreciate pointing me to such.

Comment: Frameworks won't really help you there, see @Oswin Noetzelmann's  excellent answer - it is all about service boundaries design and using pull instead of push. Data modelling is hard to do right at first iteration so Fowler recommends building monolith first and then splitting it: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html His other articles worth reading as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Managing Data Access Between Modules

#### What Is A Module?

A module is a piece of software that has a functionality by itself. A module can be deployed together with others modules as a monolith or seperately as a microservice. When defining a module one should be careful because managing data access between modules becomes harder. Thus it requires a good amount of experience in a specific field to decide. It's better to make the mistake of merging "actual two modules" into one rather than seperating a "single module" into two. Because if you seperate a module into two when you shouldn't there are going to be lots of data acces between these modules, which can be pretty hard to manage especially if there is transactional logic. But sometimes it is necessary to make modules espeacilly when things start to get big. Here is a decision tree I use to decide which kind of strategy I must choose:

#### Decision Tree For Data Reads

If there are two services such that A depends on B...

- and they are in the same module...

  - and A requires a simple data read: A should use the interface of B which is implemented by direct database read.
  - and A requires complex data read<sup>1</sup> : direct database table join should be used for reads.
- and they are in different modules...

  - and A requires simple data read...

    - and they are deployed as monolith: A should use the interface of B which is implemented with direct database read.
    - and they are deployed as microservices:  A should use the interface of B which is implemented with a http client.
  - and A requires a complex data read...

    - and they are deployed as monolith: A should copy data from B in a different format optimized for its use case by consuming from an in-memory event bus.
    - and they are deployed as microservices: A should copy data from B in a different format optimized for its use case using an event bus consumer.

#### Decision Tree For Data Writes

If there are two services such that A depends on B...

- and they are deployed as a monolith: interface of B should be implemented with direct database write.
- and they are deployed as microservices... (might require distributed transaction management between services)

  - and A requires simple data write: A should use the interface of B which is implemented with a HttpClient.
  - and A requires complex data write<sup>2</sup> : A should use the interface of B which is implemented with an event bus poducer.

complex data read<sup>1</sup>: batch processing, ordering/filtering aftrer join, transaction management etc.
complex data write<sup>2</sup>: IO intensive, CPU intensive, Network intensive