# Data integrity across the databases of different Microservices

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, rdbms, microservices

I am using relational databases for my microservices. I have `CustomersMService` which has its own database with table `Customer`, then I have `OrdersMService` which also has its own database but with table `Order`, and that table has column `CustomerId`. How can I ensure data integrity between databases, so `Orders` won't point to non-existent `Customers`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Consistency Across Microservices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950808/data-consistency-across-microservices)

Comment: The answer depends on what DBMS (or systems that are supplying DBMS-like functionality) you are using. Please add appropriate tag(s). The topic is distributed datbases.

Answer (score 15):

> How can I ensure data integrity between databases, so `Orders` won't point to non-existent `Customers`?

There is an important dimension missing, which is that of the *span of time* over which you wish to establish the referential integrity.

If you ask, "How can I ensure that all my data is 100% consistent at all times?" - you can't. If you want that you will need to enforce it, either via foreign key constraints (which are unavailable across databases), or by never writing to more than one database outside of a distributed transaction (which would defeat the purpose of using service orientation).

If you ask, "How can I ensure that all my data is 100% consistent after a reasonable span of time?", then there are *things* you can do. A common approach is to implement durable, asynchronous [eventing](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/EventMessage.html) between your services. This ensures that changes can be written locally and then dispatched remotely in a reliable, but offline, manner. A further approach is a caretaker process which periodically remediates inconsistencies in your data.

However, outside of a transaction, even over a reasonable span of time, consistency is impossible to guarantee. If absolute consistency is a requirement for your application then microservices may not be the right approach.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how asynchronous eventing can be used to prevent inconsistencies in the data.

Comment: @MehdiCharife the goal of eventing is not to "prevent inconsistencies" but to minimise them. Your architecture and tech stack will to an extent determine how consistent you can be in real time, but generally speaking a service writes a change to its local database and then uses a durable queue or subscription to *send* the change to any other system which is interested in it. Then each system which receives the change writes the change to its own local DB.